# Convert ByteBuffer to OpenCV Mat

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, java-native-interface

I want to convert Bytebuffer to OpenCV Mat is an efficient manner.

The dirty solution is to first create a bitmap using copyPixelsFromBuffer

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(640, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(frame);
```

and then convert Bitmap to Mat using OpenCV utils.

```
Mat mat = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, mat);
```

which is slow

Please help me with an elegant solution

Comment: No. I am reading images from USB camera. https://github.com/saki4510t/OpenCVwithUVC/blob/master/opencv/src/main/jni/imageproc/ImageProcessor.cpp Line 241 is calling the Java method at line 677 in https://github.com/saki4510t/OpenCVwithUVC/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/serenegiant/opencvwithuvc/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy with the below solution. Assuming that `frame` is the input `ByteBuffer`

```
byte[] data = new byte[frame.capacity()];
((ByteBuffer) frame.duplicate().clear()).get(data);
Mat mat = new Mat(480, 640, CvType.CV_8UC4);
mat.put(0, 0, data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: this is untested code.

If you know the properties (width,height,type etc) of the image then you could.

```
byte[] data = byteBuffer.array()
Mat mat = new Mat(width, height, CvType.CV_8UC3);
mat.put(0, 0, data);
```

Keep in mind that OpenCV creates images as B,G,R by default.

Comment: Good. This snippet only needs a check that the ByteBuffer is not direct but is [array-based](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#hasArray()).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with `ByteBuffer` but if you can get a pointer to the buffer (via [`GetDirectBufferAddress()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetDirectBufferAddress)?), you can use this Mat constructor [`Mat(Size size, int type, void* data, size_t step)`](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a") that will not do any copying.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful.

```
byte[] bytes = frame.array();      
Mat mat = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(bytes), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```